# ¿Qué significa "es posible bien sea"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Qué significa la frase "*es posible bien sea*" en la siguiente oración?  Fue traduccida de inglés y opino que es una mala traducción.

> *De estos datos, es posible bien sea probar la hipótesis que estar de pie no incrementa la frecuencia del pulso, en promedio, o estimar la
>   diferencia en pulso medio entre aquellos de pie o aquellos sentados.*

---

What does "*es posible bien sea*" mean in the above sentence? This was translated from English and I think it is a bad translation.

Comment: "bien sea .... o ... " == "Either ... or ..."

Answer (score 4):

La frase tiene algunos errores, entre ellos el uso de *bien sea*; pero no porque no pueda utilizarse, sino porque debe repetirse. En español hay algunas conjunciones disyuntivas que se usan repetidas, delante de cada una de las opciones. Una de ellas es *bien... bien*. Lo que no puede hacerse es utilizarse delante de una opción y luego utilizar otra distinta delante de la otra opción, como se hace aquí (*bien... o*).

Por tanto, lo correcto es:

> De estos datos es posible, bien sea probar la hipótesis de que estar de
>   pie no incrementa la frecuencia del pulso, en promedio, bien estimar la
>   diferencia en pulso medio entre aquellos de pie y aquellos sentados.

Comment: ¿Puede darme un enlace donde explica el uso de "bien sea...bien" más?

Comment: @Dombey En http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=bien, punto 3, se explica que debe usarse ante dos o más elementos; ante uno solo es incorrecto. En realidad, el *sea* no es necesario en la frase original, aunque tampoco creo que sea incorrecto.

Comment: además, están mal puestas las comas en el texto original, lo que estropea el sentido de la frase. EL Texto de Gorpik es correcto, tanto en el uso de las palabras como en el uso de las comas.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the sentence is grammatically correct (except that it should say `aquellos de pie **y** aquellos sentados`). I say this because it is extremely tangled; the English source must be just as ugly!

As belisarius commented, `bien sea` is used here in the sense of `either` It would be more natural to use `o bien`. Let's untangle the mess. Depending on the data, one of two scenarios is valid:

- It is possible to show that, in average, standing does not increase pulse rate.
- It is possible to estimate the difference in pulse rate between standing and seating subjects.

(Notice that the Spanish sentence is well constructed in that it uses "es posible" *outside* the disjunction.)

Part of the problem with the sentence is that it is an empty statement. Obviously the pulse rates data will be the same for standing and seating subjects, or not. In one case we show it is invariant, in the other case we measure the discrepancy... D'oh!

Here is an alternative way to say the same in Spanish.

> Si los datos no muestran un mayor pulso promedio en individuos de pie, entonces permitirán estimar la diferencia entre el pulso promedio de sujetos sentados y de pie.

Comment: The English original is not bad but the Spanish translator really botched it. But why is it that it's well constructed if "es posible" is used outside the disjunction?